# jquery, work with date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

how in jQuery work date?
I want to perform mathematical operations to date.

```
var date = '2010-11-23 21:32:31';
var date = date - 70;
alert(date);
```

how get: 
2010-11-23 21:31:21

Thanks

Comment: There is no "jQuery" way to work with date objects. It's strictly javascript/ECMAscript.

Comment: Edited tags: leaving in jQuery since the original poster asked it.

Comment: See related asked a couple hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016318/how-to-get-difference-of-saved-time-and-current-time-in-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

http://www.datejs.com/

It's not jQuery, but will solve your problems.

From their sample page:

```
// What date is next thrusday?
Date.today().next().thursday();

// Add 3 days to Today
Date.today().add(3).days();

// Is today Friday?
Date.today().is().friday();

// Number fun
(3).days().ago();

// 6 months from now
var n = 6;
n.months().fromNow();

// Set to 8:30 AM on the 15th day of the month
Date.today().set({ day: 15, hour: 8, minute: 30 });

// Convert text into Date
Date.parse('today');
Date.parse('t + 5 d'); // today + 5 days
Date.parse('next thursday');
Date.parse('February 20th 1973');
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00');
```

Comment: I dunno if you remember this issue but well I just read it and tried the datejs library and it is not working for me and I really dunno why, I included it in my project like I've done with so many other libraries and, as [this](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) describes I called alert(Date.today()) to give it a try and nothing, my browser's web console outputs 'TypeError: Date.today is not a function' although when I'm typing in my .js file it even autocompletes the function and recognizes de date.js file. Tips appreciated please!

Comment: @jmiguel, please create a new question describing what you tried, so others can help you too. Also, consider that maybe datejs is a little outdated (their last released version is from 2007), try http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a jQuery question as it is more a javascript question. For that answer, have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp.